# XCode multiple errors (No such command "-no_deduplicate")

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, xcode8

I've build an app which is using firebase auth, database, storage and core.
But when I build my app, there are coming multiple errors, one of them is

> "No such command: '-no_deduplicate'".

And file-not-found errors that are searching any simulator architecture file containing the path `/i386/`, but I haven't memorized them.

Thank you for your help,
MarvMan

Comment: could you put the error log and reformulate the question ; explain your logic , this would be perfect if you copy paste also the part that generate the question from your code.

Comment: Thank you, i've reinstalled firebase using cocoapods and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC it's a warning and if you run your app in build mode instead of dev mode this specific warning goes away

Comment: Thank you, i've reinstalled firebase using cocoapods and then it worked.

Comment: No problem. Would you mind upvoting/accepting my answer if it has worked?